# InternetException("NO INTERNET - Pywhatkit needs active internet connection")

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using pywhatkit module to play a song in youtube in python.
I have already installed pywhatkit using pip.My code is given below:

```
import pywhatkit as kit

kit.playonyt('Jhon Lennon')
```

Now it gives me an error while executing it.The error is given below:

raise InternetException("NO INTERNET - Pywhatkit needs active internet connection")

InternetException: NO INTERNET - Pywhatkit needs active internet connection

My internet connection is absolutely fine.I have checked it. I am new in Python and have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I would have expected a `YouDontKnowTheBeatlesNamesException`.

Comment: Did you find what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved that modifying the pywhatkit library.
The problem came from the request.get() method

In the file "main.py" I commented the line "requests.get("https://www.google.com")" as it triggered the Exception "NO INTERNET - Pywhatkit needs active internet connection"

I have not checked how that affects the rest of the code but the instant whatsapp messages works

Answer (score 0):

At line 37 in core.py (path_to_python\Python\Lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\core\core.py) - the check_connection function - I have added the following proxy settings I needed:

```
    proxies = {
   'http': 'http://proxy.corporateurl.com:80',
   'https': 'http://proxy.corporateurl.com:80',
   }
    try:
        requests.get("https://google.com", proxies=proxies)
```

Worked like a charm afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

I just copied the code and run it and this is what it gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    kit.playont('Jhon Lennon')
AttributeError: module 'pywhatkit' has no attribute 'playont'
```

I think you meant this:

```
import pywhatkit as kit

kit.playonyt('Jhon Lennon')
```

You forgot to add "y" in playonyt.

Why don't you try this and check if it works.

also try:

```
pip install pywhatkit --upgrade
```

If it doesn't then try these:
`ifconfig` if you are on Linux and `ipconfig` if you are on windows and check if your local Ip shows up. If it does, then you can say you are connected.

Also try this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

if you get reply then you can be sure that there is network.

Comment: Thanks for all possible Solutions.I have tried with including "Y" that I have missed, then upgraded the version and finally use ping coomand and got this "Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 49ms, Average = 34ms" but still getting the same error.

Comment: It means that the Internet connection is working fine. I am afraid I may not be able to help you. However if you are using Windows, then the default browser might be configured to Internet explorer right? Pywhatkit just opens up the default browser but I don't think it will work with IE. Try changing it to any other browser. Also there are few problems I can think of. If you use proxy or any proxy extension such as foxyproxy, then it may be the problem with that. If you still arrive at the problem, please comment about your system, OS, Browser e.t.c.

Comment: No, though I am using windows but my default browser is chrome.I have changed it earlier.